# Type Error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello everybody good day.

I have some question about this it makes me struggle.

about an error that "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" I Dont know how to fix it. I know its a silly question but anyone can help me out?

**Heres my code :**

in this block of code It's the input

```
l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "ID",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=7)
t4 = tk.Entry(window, width=16, bd=3, bg="light blue")
t4.grid(column=2, row=7)
```

And this is code is for registration to database:

def register():

```
if (t1.get()==""  or t2.get()=="" or t3.get()=="" or t4.get()==""):
    messagebox.showinfo("Result","Please Complete the Provided Details!")

else:
    databases = mysql.connector.connect(
    host ="localhost",
    user = "userdata",
    password = "",
    database = "facerecog"
    )

    cursors = databases.cursor()
    cursors.execute("SELECT * from record")
    result = cursors.fetchall()

    id= t4.get()+str()
    for x in result:

        id += 1

        sql = "INSERT INTO record(ids, names,course_year,positions) values(%s ,%s ,%s , %s)"
        val = (id, t1.get(), t2.get(), t3.get())
        cursors.execute(sql,val)
        databases.commit()
```

**But It makes Error that Shows This:**

File "c:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/final_recog/Recog.py", line 77, in register
id += 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Dont know how to fix it anyone can Help me out?

**Thank you In Advance**

[image: Heres the Photo of ID to Be inputed]

Comment: it makes same result an error id += 1 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Change `id= t4.get()+str()` to `id = int(t4.tet())`, but you need to cater invalid input of `t4`.  Also should those lines after `id += 1` outside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

replace  `id= t4.get()+str()` with  `id= t4.get()`. If you need to use id somewhere where it must be a string then use the str() function to cast

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` must be a`str`, not an `int`:

[image]

You can fix this by converting the `id` when you add to it:

```py
>>> id = "1"
>>> id = int(id) + 1
>>> id
2
```

Comment: How  Can I fix this? id= t4.get()

Comment: Cause I want to Input The ID That's why I put ID= t4.get()

Comment: Edited my post with a fix that may work.

Comment: IT WORKKKKSSS THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHH A lot of THANKS BRO